# Passing javascript object to webservice via Jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, object

I have a webservice that returns an object

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<User> ContractorApprovals()
```

I also have a webservice that accepcts an object

```
[WebMethod]
    public bool SaveContractor(Object u)
```

When I make my webservice calls via Jquery:

```
function ServiceCall(method, parameters, onSucess, onFailure) {
    var parms = "{" + (($.isArray(parameters)) ? parameters.join(',') : parameters) + "}"; // to json
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "services/"+method,
        data: parms,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            if (typeof onSucess == 'function' || typeof onSucess == 'object')
                onSucess(msg.d);
        },
            error: function(msg, err) {
            $("#dialog-error").dialog('open');}
});
```

I can call the first one just fine. My onSucess function gets passed a javascript object exactly structured like my User object on the service.

However, I am now having trouble getting the object back to the server.

I'm accepting Object as a parameter on the server side so I can't inagine there is an issue there. So I'm thinking something is wrong with the parms on the client side but i'm not sure what...

I am doing something to the effect

```
ServiceCall("AuthorizationManagerWorkManagement.asmx/ContractorApprovals",
      "",
      function(data,args){$("#div").data('user',data[0])},
      null)
```

then

```
ServiceCall("AuthorizationManagerWorkManagement.asmx/SaveContractor",
      JSON.stringify({u: $("#div").data("user")}) //dont work $("#div").data('user'), //These also do not work: "{'u': ' + $("#div").data("user") + '}", NOR JSON.stringify({u: userObject})
      function(data,args){(alert(data)},
      null)
```

I know the first service call works, I can get the data. The second one is causing the "onFailure" method to execute rather then "OnSuccess".

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I chaed my last code block to use : `JSON.stringify({u: $("#div").data("user")})`

I now get `Invalid object passed in, member name expected. (1):`

But I have no idea what the means... Google has turned up plenty of that error, but no problem like mine...

Comment: start by using the Firebug add-on to FireFox; enable the console tab so you can check the response of each ajax call, could be exception in your server side code? or issue with how parameters are sent?

Comment: will ie developer tools do? Developing app for ie8... I turned debuggin on, and ran the ajax call and nothing happend on the debugger. Do i have to turn something on?

Comment: OK. The issue is that somehow the string ebing returned by `JSON.stringify()` has an additional set of wrapping `{}` brackets. I did `params = parms.substring(1,parms.length-1);`. However I don't like this solution. Does anyone know the right way to solve it? I'm guessing it has to do with the brackets i'm passing into the stringify function, but I don't know how else to do it...

Answer (score 0):

```
 ServiceCall("AuthorizationManagerWorkManagement.asmx/SaveContractor",
            "{u: " + JSON.stringify($("#div").data("user")) + "}",
            function(data, args) { alert(data); },
            FailedServiceCall);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have posted the code as well as a link over Click [here](http://prashiddha.com.np/?page_id=202)!

```
    Default.aspx
        <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"   Inherits="_Default" %>             
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld")%>';
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#txtAutoSuggest').keyup(function() {
                var str = $("#txtAutoSuggest").val();
                var a = JSON.stringify({ name: str });
                CallService(a);
                  });

        });

     function CallService(a) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: a,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
           success: function(data, status) {
                $('#lblResult').text(data.d);
            },
            error: Error
        });
    }
    function Error(request, status, error) {
        $('#lblResult').text("Not Matched");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAutoSuggest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="lblResult" Text="&nbsp;" Width="100%" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

OR

application.js

```
 var url = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld")%>';
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#txtAutoSuggest').keyup(function() {
                var str = $("#txtAutoSuggest").val();
                var a = JSON.stringify({ name: str });
                CallService(a);
            });

        });

    function CallService(a) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: a,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data, status) {
                $('#lblResult').text(data.d);
            },
            error: Error
        });
    }
    function Error(request, status, error) {
        $('#lblResult').text("Not Matched");
    }




<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="WebService" %>
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;




 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
 [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
```

// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX or JQuery.

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
 public class WebService  : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld(string name)
    {
        Utility ut = new Utility();  // some class where you will have your database connection
        ArrayList suggestedProblemName = ut.getItems(name);  // some method of the class
        return ""+suggestedProblemName[0];
    } 
}
```